# Stubbing of mockito mock object on spock-based test

Tags: mockito, spock

I'm using Spock fw with Mockito. I have a controller named 'HostController' and a service named 'HostService'.

The 'HostController' has the method called as `host(Long id)` and 'HostService' has the method called as `findOne(Long id)`.

I want to test `HostController#host(Long id)`, so I think of stubbing `findOne(Long id)` method.

Follow is test code:

```
class MockTest extends Specification {
    @Mock
    private HostService mockedService;

    @InjectMocks
    private HostController controller;

    def setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    def "mock test"() {
        given:
        def host = new Host(id: 1, ipAddress: "127.0.0.1", hostName: "host1")
        mockedService.findOne(_) >> host

        when:
        Map<String, Object> result = controller.host(1)

        then:
        result.get("host") != null
    }
}
```

In above test, `controller.host(1)` return `Map<String, Object>` type and it has the key named `host`. I assumed that the key hasn't null value, but it has null value.

Why doesn't work as I think?

Answer (score 6):

I found one of solutions.

In above example, I tried to stub `HostService#findOne(Long id)` method using Spock like `mockedService.findOne(_) >> host`. Perhaps it seems not to fit with mock object of Mockito.

[Rene Enriquez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2697734/rene-enriquez) introduce Spock Mock to me. It works very well. However, I want to use @InjectMocks and @Mock. To do that, we follow Mockito mocking and stubbing instruction.(Thank you, Enriquez)

Modified example is:

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

class MockTest extends Specification {
    @Mock
    private HostService mockedService;

    @InjectMocks
    private HostController controller;

    def setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    def "mock test"() {
        given:
        def host = new Host(id: 1, ipAddress: "127.0.0.1", hostName: "host1")
        when(mockedService.findOne(1)).thenReturn(host)

        when:
        Map<String, Object> result = controller.host(1)

        then:
        result.get("host") != null
    }
}
```

We can use Mockito stubbing, not Spock's. It works well!

Comment: To help you with spock mocks, Spock also has annotations to setup mocks from the Subject Collaborator extension: https://github.com/marcingrzejszczak/spock-subjects-collaborators-extension

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
import spock.lang.Specification

class MySpec extends Specification {
   HostController controller

   def setup() {
       controller = new HostController()
   }

   def "mock test"() {
        given:
        HostService mockedService = Mock(HostService)
        def host = new Host(id: 1, ipAddress: "127.0.0.1", hostName: "host1")
        mockedService.findOne(_) >> host
        controller.service = mockedService

        when:
        Map<String, Object> result = controller.host(1)

        then:
        result.get("host") != null
    }
}
```

Comment: It works fine well. But I want to use Mockito instead of Spock Mock.

Comment: Ooops and sorry for my insistence, but, Why?